# Server & client messenger using winsock in c++ without threads

Tags: winsock

currently I have a server and a client console application in c++ using winsock. In my situation the client is able to send a message to the server, which listens and it can aswer, but I need to make them to be able to always recieve and send messages to one another.

My problem is I can not use threads, I need to achieve this goal without them. How can this be done by sockets and loops? Any hint is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use threads, you have to do `send` and `recv` in the same loop. Rather than doing it blindly it's better to use **`select`** function to check whether is there any incoming massages from any of the sockets or is it possible to write (send) data in to the socket. [This is a reference to study about select function.](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select)